# Pandas Group By column to generate quantiles (.25, 0.5, .75)

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say we have `CityName, Min-Temperature, Max-Temperature, Humidity` of different cities.

We need an output dataframe grouped on `CityName` and want to generate `0.25, 0.5 and 0.75` quantiles. New column names would be `OldColunmName + ('Q1)/('Q2')/('Q3')`.

**Example INPUT**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'cityName': pd.Categorical(['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b']),
                   'MinTemp': [1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 1.1, 2, 2.1, 2.2, 2.4, 2.5, 1.11, 1.31, 2.1, 1, 2, 2.3,  2.1],
                   'MaxTemp': [2.1, 4.2, 5.1, 2.13, 4, 3.1, 5.2, 3.4, 3.5, 2.11, 2.31, 3.1, 2,  4.3, 4.3, 3.1],
                   'Humidity': [0.29, 0.19, .45, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2,  0.5, 0.11, 0.31, 0.1, .1, .2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.1]
                  })
```

[image]

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**First Approach**

First you have to group your data on the column you want which is `'cityName'`. Then, because on each column you want to do multiple and different kinds of aggregations, you can use `'agg'` function. For functions in the `'agg'`, you cannot give parameters so you define them as follow:

```
def quantile_50(x):
    return x.quantile(0.5)

def quantile_25(x):
    return x.quantile(0.25)

def quantile_75(x):
    return x.quantile(0.75)

quantile_df = df.groupby('cityName').agg([quantile_25, quantile_50, quantile_75])
quantile_df
```

**Second Approach**

You can use `describe` method and select the statistics you need. By using `idx` you can choose which subindex to choose.

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.groupby('cityName').describe().loc[:, idx[:, ['25%', '50%', '75%']]]
```

Comment: There are a couple of fields. In this Exaple only 'City' is to be Grouped UpOn and There are 3 fields on which I need quantiles. Could you please expand your answer with example code

Comment: @VZG I would be happy to give you the code, but I need your dataframe. Please add your dataframe the way you have it in your code (a reproducible dataframe) so that you can be helped better

Comment: Updated the Question with a Data Frame, Please do the needful

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to SoftCode the colunm Names.
I have about 100 + and its insane Wide

Comment: @VZG yeah, there is another elegant way of doing it which I will add to my answer right now